# Elasticsearch 1.5.0 - failed to connect to requesting node

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch running on a windows machine (10.0.0.51 on my network). I have deployed an app to a linux virtual machine (10.0.0.10). When my app starts it tries to connect to Elasticsearch and create a node using the Java API:

```
node = nodeBuilder().client(true).clusterName(CLUSTER_NAME).node();
client = node.client();
```

However in the Elasticsearch console I get the error:

```
[2015-04-15 14:28:10,559][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Matt Murdock] failed to connect to requesting node [Gatecrasher][dFF2VpWTQvCrilRKyVSC5Q][localhost.localdomain][inet[/10.0.0.10:9300]]{data=false, client=true}
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [Gatecrasher][inet[/10.0.0.10:9300]] connect_timeout[30s]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:797)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:731)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:704)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:216)
        at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.MulticastZenPing$Receiver$1.run(MulticastZenPing.java:542)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: /10.0.0.10:9300
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:716)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:152)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
        ... 3 more
```

I can connect to Elasticsearch when running both apps from the same machine.

**UPDATE**:

I just loaded elastic search on to the same VM as my app and I couldn't connect. I can only connect when running my app from and Elastic search on the same windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

It was a network issue with my Linux machine. I did various things including turning ofrf the firewall and it started working. I think that the firewall was blocking access.